# Inconsistent data output from Kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to pull data from Kafka consumer to pass it on to my application. Below is the code that I have written to access the consumer:

```
public class ConsumerGroup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String topic = "kafka_topic";
        String group = "0";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", group);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
        System.out.println("Subscribed to topic: " + topic);

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, sometimes the data is getting generated and sometimes no data is generated. Why this behavior is inconsistent? Is there any issue with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is Ok. You have autocommit option enabled, so after you read the records, they are automatically committed to Kafka. Every time when you run the code you start from the last processed offset, which is stored in __consumer_offsets topic. So you always read only the new records, which have arrived to Kafka after last run. To print the data constantly in the consumer app, you should put constantly new records into your topic.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I do not want to consume only the latest records inserted after the previous hit. I want to fetch all the data present in kafka and therefore I am not deleting the data in the kafka topic after fetching. Is there a way to fetch all the data?

Comment: You should either use `KafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning` method or just use every time new value for group.id property as offsets are stored per group.id

Comment: I have only one topic and I am not using any partition, what value should be passed in the parameter "Collection<TopicPartition>" while calling the method KafkaConsumer.seekToBeginnng(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)?

Comment: `Set<TopicPartition> assignments = consumer.assignment();
 assignments.forEach(topicPartition -> 
 consumer.seekToBeginning(Arrays.asList(topicPartition)));`